# Access instance variable in python

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I have a classes a and b as below:

```
class a(object):
    counter=10
    def __init__(self):        
        self.counter=1
    def process(self):
        self.counter+=1
        return self.counter

class b(a):
    def __init__(self,a_obj):
        self.counter=a_obj.counter
    def process(self):
        result=self.counter
        return (result)
```

My so called main function is as :

```
a_object=a()
b_object=b(a)

for x in range(1,6):
    print(a_object.process())

print(b_object.process())
```

My results for which are as below:

```
2
3
4
5
6
10
```

But I want to have access to the last updated value of counter in A i.e. 6 (referencing the instance variable) rather than 10 (which is the value of the class variable).

Please advise where am I going wrong with this.

Comment: do you just want `new_var = b_object.process()`? ...

Comment: no, I am looking to access the last updated value in class a (in the example it is last updated as 6) and use it in class b for some operation (as of this example , just print)

Comment: Don't mix instance and class variables. They will be hard to trace when inheritance is involved.

Comment: So... you want `new_var = a_object.process()` inside the loop?

Comment: Use `a.counter` in `a.__init__` and `a.process` instead of `self.counter`. `self.counter` is referencing instance variable,which will be separate for each instance of the class. `a.counter` refers to the variable `counter` which is shared by all instances of `a`

Comment: You are passing `a` to `b` constructor when you probably want to pass `a_object`

Comment: You need to call `b(a_object)`, not `b(a)`.

Comment: `a_obj.counter` is a *immutable object*. Keeping a reference to it is pointless, keep a reference to `a_obj` instead.

Comment: a_object=a()
b_object=b(a_object)    even using this gets me the last value as 1 i.e. the __init__ function is being used again to reset the values back to start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no point in keeping a reference to `a_obj.counter`. All you are doing is creating a new reference to an immutable object. You are *not* referencing the attribute on `a_obj`, only the object that `a_obj.counter` *also* points to.

But when `a.process()` is run, the `counter` reference is *replaced* by one that points to a different integer object. `b.counter` still references the initial value.

You want to keep a reference to `a_obj` itself, so you can ask it what the `counter` attribute *there* points to whenever you need it:

```
class b(a):
    def __init__(self, a_obj):
        self.a_obj = a_obj
    def process(self):
        result = self.a_obj.counter
        return result
```

You may want to read up on how Python names and attributes work; they are merely little name tags tied to the actual object. See [Ned Batchelder's excellent *Facts and myths about Python names and values* article](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that totally made sense and your explanation also gave me much clarity on the subject. Cheers.

Comment: It also worths noting that in original code `counter=10` declares it as the **class** member, not the **instance** member, which is not necessary and even confusing in this case. **Instance** fields should be defined in constructor only